# How to change the CMD python directory?

Tags: python, cmd.exe

So at the moment when I try to launch my code from the CMD terminal, it forces me to use the following line to launch python:

```
py
```

But for some of my programs I need to use the:

```
python
```

code in order to be able to run my code. Is there a way to change the Python initiation line from 'py' to 'python'?

Comment: Which programs behave this way? Have you checked to see what is actually running in CMD when you type "py" and referenced that to an entry in your PATH statement? Please EDIT your question to add contextualizing and clarifying information to help us better understand your situation. Also, please add a TAG for the operating system and version you are currently running.

Answer (score 1):

`py.exe` is the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) and is a separate program from any given `python.exe`. However, its intended purpose is to allow multiple versions of Python to be ran with minimal fuss. So, for instance, if you hypothetically needed to run Python 2.7 or Python 3.6, you could just use something like e.g. `py -2.7` or `py -3.6` (assuming both were versions which were installed and recognized on your system).

> But for some of my programs I need to use `python` in order to be able to run my code.

If you really wish to use a single version of Python from the command line, simply add the folder where your prefered `python.exe` resides to your PATH/Path variable(s).

On Windows 7:

- Go to `Control Panel\System and Security\System`.
- Click the `Advanced system settings` link.
- Select the `Advanced` tab from the `System Properties` dialog box and click the `Environment Variables...` button.
- `Edit` your PATH (User) and/or Path (System) variables to include e.g. `C:\path\to\your\preferred\python.exe` (remember to put a `;` at the end of the last listed path before putting the path to your `python.exe`).
- Click `OK` when finished.

In Windows 10, you can:

- Search for the `Control Panel` from the Start Menu.

  Or you can:
- Search for `env` from the Start Menu and click the link to edit your environment variables.
- You will still need to click the `Environment Variables...` button in either case under the `Advanced` tab from the `System Properties` dialog box.
- Click `Edit` and add your `C:\path\to\your\preferred\python.exe` path to the appropriate PATH (User) and/or Path (System) variable list.
- Click `OK` when finished.

`python` should now be available from the command line. If you are still having trouble running it, you may need to log out and then log back in (rebooting is typically unnecessary).

---

**"Python" As A Batch File**

While a bit of a hack, you can also "alias" `py.exe` as `python` with a batch file.

Create a new `.txt` file and and put e.g.:

```
C:\path\to\your\py.exe %*
```

Save it and rename it to `python.bat`.

Then place this batch file in your PATH\Path variable(s), as above (ex. as `C:\path\to\your\python.bat`).

In this case, you're still using `py.exe` in the background but using `python` (a.k.a. `python.bat`) to call it. The `%*` notation  allows any variables (e.g. script names, options, etc.) to be passed along automatically to `py.exe`.

*To be clear, you can simply use `python` from the command line with this method. You do not need to use `python.bat`.*

---

*As a final, final note, while not recommended, you could also probably simply change the name of `py.exe` to `python.exe` if you really wanted to.*

---